# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when trying to get resources from site in same domain?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, access-control

I'm merely trying to grab the html from one of my other sites on the server and print it on the current site. Here's basically what I'm doing:

```
// The object
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

// When a button is pressed, we get the html
function printJSON(action)
{
    otherURL = "http://www.my.domain.com/other.php?action=" +action;

    xmlhttp.open('GET',otherURL,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

// and then print it in this div
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        $('JSON_output').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

and the error I'm receiving is:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.my.domain.com/other.php?action=SEARCH. Origin http://my.domain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Which seems strange, because this is one site on the server trying to access another site right within the same folder. Is there something I need to adjust on my server? An attribute in xmlhttp I need to set?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.my.domain.com and http://my.domain.com are two different domains (note the www) according to [the JavaScript same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

If www.my.domain.com and my.domain.com point to the same place, the simplest solution would be to make `otherURL` relative; start it with "/other.php?action="; that way, it will always be on the same domain as your page.

If they do not, point to the same place, there is a much more complicated solution involving your server outputting additional headers called [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/); [here's an overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control).

Comment: You're a stud, thanks. I wasn't sure just what 'domain' implied. Now I know, and have a working site! In one minute overflow will allow me to accept this answer.